# PHP file_put_contents , generate filename dynamic according to date fail

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to accomplish the following:
Generate textfile with response to different time.
Example "example_17/2/2016_22:25:49.txt"

I try using &filename.&date but cannot work. Is it any simple and good solution? Thanks a lot for help ~

The code is attach below

```
<?php
$timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
$date  = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"].$date; // The file name


if(isset($_POST['myselect']) && isset($_POST['textarea'])) {
$data = $_POST['myselect'] . "\n" . $_POST['textarea'] . "\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('/home/pi/Desktop/DMixer_Webinterface_Downloadfile/$fileName.$date', $data);


if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    echo "$ret bytes written to file";
echo "The".$date;
}
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

Comment: The date has slashes in it, meaning it will assume those are sub-directories and not part of the file name. You can't write to a file without first creating the directory it resides in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
    $date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $fileName = 'abc';
    $fileName = $fileName.'_'.$date;
    $data = 'Hi';
    $path = '/home/pi/Desktop/DMixer_Webinterface_Downloadfile/'.$fileName.'.txt';
    $ret = file_put_contents($path, $data);
```

The date format before will be treated as directory ,dont forget to add write permission.

Comment: I had try this code. I always get "There was an error writing this file"

Comment: What does this sentences means ?
The date format before will be treated as directory ,dont forget to add write permission.
Any example ? I am new to php

Comment: I had try in my linux. it success. maybe some problems with your directory permission?

Comment: the string '/'of pre format will be treated as directory .Example .'17/2/14' when cant find  this directory  .it will be error .

Comment: write permission .use chmod for linux to get the wirite permission of '/home/pi/Desktop/DMixer_Webinterface_Downloadfile/' .after that ,u can save file in the path

Comment: I also work on linux, the file permission I have open to anyone. If i write in this way it can work but cannot include date
$path = '/home/pi/Desktop/DMixer_Webinterface_Downloadfile/.$fileName';

Comment: The semicolon there will cause issue ? If close before $fileName will have echo back "An error writing to this files" . But if close after $fileName it just save as $fileName.txt

Comment: Oh It can work, my initial date format is / and need to change to - as mention , thanks a lots ~~~

Comment: Change the format of the date .dont use slashes  . $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') .add  $date to $filename .

Comment: your should take a closer look at the first row of my answer  ;)